# Is deleting vector<vector<MyClass>> thread save?

Tags: c++, vector, thread-safety, openmp

my question is,  whether it is possible to delete an element from an inner vector, like `vector<vector<Myclass> a; a[i].erease(a[i].begin());`, if the threads are operating on different inner vectors?
I know that modyfing a vector isn't thread save, but in this case every thread has its own vector.

Comment: If every vector can ONLY be operated on by one thread then there is no need for thread synchronization. So yes in this case it would be thread safe.

Comment: I agree with @MohamadElghawi. In your case if each of the thread has its own vector, the whole process is thread-safe.

Comment: This is interesting, because e.g. push_back needs resize to work correct.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting an element in a vector on deleting a vector are **not** thread safe.

But thread safety only makes sense, if multiple threads can access the same data. For a single threaded program, or if each thread only processes its own data, even thread unsafe operation **are** safe.

So the answer is: it is not thread safe, but is harmless provided the vector can only be accessed by one single thread.

Comment: Are you sure? I have to use resize before i can push_back something in vecter<vector<Myclass>>. Why is there not such a problem with erease/delete?